# Save purchases in sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am using `in-app purchase`.
I make purchases in a specific `Activity` and I store in `sharedpreferences`.
There is no problem so far. Now I want to use these sharedpreferences` in another class and check that if a payment is made a specific task is to be done.
My code :

```
    `@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_premium);


        btnBuy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuy);
        btnBuy.setEnabled(false);
        btnBuy.setOnClickListener(this);

        mBillingProcessor = new BillingProcessor(
                this,
                BAZAAR_RSA_KEY,
                NIVAD_APPLICATION_ID,
                NIVAD_APPLICATION_SECRET,
                MarketName.CAFE_BAZAAR,
                this

        );


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mBillingProcessor.purchase(this, FULL_VERSION_SKU);

    }

        @Override
                public void onBillingInitialized() {
            btnBuy.setEnabled(true);
            btnBuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor( R.color.colorBoy));
            btnBuy.setText(R.string.Buy);
        }

        @Override
    public void onProductPurchased(String sku, TransactionDetails transactionDetails) {
            if (FULL_VERSION_SKU.equals(sku)) {

                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PremiumActivity.this)
                        .edit().putBoolean("is_full_version", true).apply();
                Toast.makeText(PremiumActivity.this, R.string.Lol, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }

        }


        @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
        if(mBillingProcessor.isPurchased(FULL_VERSION_SKU)){
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PremiumActivity.this)
                    .edit().putBoolean("is_full_version", true).apply();


        } else {
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PremiumActivity.this)
                    .edit().putBoolean("is_full_version", false).apply();
        }
       }

        @Override
    public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable throwable){
        if (errorCode == 205){
            Toast.makeText(PremiumActivity.this, R.string.nivad_protects_this_application, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mBillingProcessor != null) {
            mBillingProcessor.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!mBillingProcessor.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    } `
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `getDefaultSharedPreferences` will create a shared preference file for **Internal Activity only.**

You should get an instance of `SharedPreferences` like this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("NAME",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

2.In another activity, just get the data out like what you do inside the previous Activity

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.getBoolean("is_full_version", false);
```